# Is it bad practice to use spans as "buttons"? W3Schools is doing that

Tags: html, semantics, w3c, semantic-markup

Consider this modal example (and a lot of other examples from them): https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp

They use a `span` tag, that acts as a close button for the modal. Isn't this semantically incorrect? Or is there some legitimisation to do that?

It is kind of weird that the "web standardisation consortium" is putting out examples like that. But maybe I am missing something here.

Comment: w3schools is not from w3c.

Comment: **Bad practice indeed**. Use `<button>` for things that trigger an **actions** which aren't an anchor link

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it bad practice to use spans as “buttons”?

Yes. They are, by default:

- Not announced as being interactive by screen readers
- Not in the tab order so are inaccessible to keyboard users

It's possible to hack around that by use of `tabindex` and ARIA, but using a real `<button>` is much simpler and better supported.

You can get a much deeper dive into this subject from [Inclusive Components by  Heydon Pickering](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/printed-books/inclusive-components/).

> W3C is doing that

No, they aren't.

W3Schools is a low-quality advert-ridden tutorial site that happens to have good SEO because they've been around forever.

They've picked a name which lets them be confused with the W3 Consortium. Note, however, that "Consortium" and "Schools" are not the same word!

Comment: Wow, and there I was thinking that this is the official platform. :D You are right, they usually rank even higher than MDN.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't a bad practice if you add there at least `tabindex` attribute. Users should reach the button via keyboard too:

```
<span tabindex="0">Button</span>
```

Also a good practice is to adding [ARIA - attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/button_role):

```
<span tabindex="0" role="button" aria-pressed="false">Button</span>
```

Comment: But this looks like a really stupid "workaround, so I don't have to use a button" scenario, that I can't find a reason to justify. But for the sake of adding a valid and helping open minded answer, take my upvote. :)

Comment: Yes, I agree the better practice is to use `<button>`.